# Problem with integrating by parts

Tags: calculus

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int x^3\cos 4x \ dx &=& \int x^3(8\cos^4 x - 8\cos^2x+1) \ dx\\
&=&\int 8x^3\cos^4x \ dx - \int 8x^3\cos^2x + \int x^3 \ dx\\
&=&8\int x^3\cos^4x \ dx - 8\int x^3\cos^2x + \frac{x^4}{4}+c \\
&=& ?
\end{eqnarray*}
I'm kind of stuck there. I'm new to integration, maybe somebody should lend me a hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have got off on the wrong foot completely. When the integrand is a polynomial times $\cos ax$, $\sin ax$, or $e^{ax}$ you should always split it so that you differentiate the polynomial and integrate the rest.

Let $u=x^3$ and $dv=\cos 4x\,dx$. Then $du=3x^2\,dx$, $v=\frac14\sin 4x$, and

$$\int x^3\cos4x\,dx=\frac14x^3\sin4x-\frac34\int x^2\sin 4x\,dx\;.$$

Now you have

$$\int x^2\sin 4x\,dx$$

to evaluate, with a lower power of $x$. Treat it the same way, and you’ll end up with an integral

$$\int x\cos 4x\,dx\;.$$

still to be evaluated. Treat *that* the same way, and you’ll end up with a simple

$$\int\sin 4x\,dx\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You should integrate the $\cos $ term, and differentiate the polynomial term.